# Storing a String variable in Android ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I need to store a hidden ID value for each row in my `ListView`. Basically a variable containing a string value that the code needs and something the user doesn't need to see.

1. User enters a value to the nameField `EditText`
2. Clicks on the saveName `Button`
3. Value gets saved to the String declared in the `ViewHolder`
4. Print it

**Note:** Keep in mind that every row has a `String` value to store. Each row has a `String` value stored in the `ViewHolder`. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

My approach was to declare a `String` variable in my `ViewHolder` class, hoping that it will retain that value for that specific row. However I noticed that when the adapter recycles that row, the string value is reseted to an empty string.

**Adapter:**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.saveName = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveName);
            holder.nameField = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Button That saves what the user entered in the nameField to the String variable
        holder.saveName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  holder.hidden_value = nameField.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        //Just to check whether the value is saved when I recycle listview when scrolling
        Log.d("test", holder.hidden_value);
        //It logs an empty string. The value from the editext was not saved! 
}

static class ViewHolder {
        EditText nameField;
        Button saveName;
        String hidden_value = "";
}
```

Why doesn't the value get saved in the string? When I try to log it, it logs an empty string! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: store your "hidden string id" in the adapter's data model

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean Data model? @pskink

Comment: Put that string into a ArrayList and call notifyDatasetChanged() in onClick method. Also in getItem(int position) and getCount() methods, use your arraylist.

Comment: what adapter are you using? where the list view data is kept? in some array, right? so store your id there

Comment: From inside the adapter? Why would I notify since the ArrayList items were not modified or deleted? I'm only editing the ViewHolder objects values

Comment: forget view holder pattern, it only makes problems like yours

Comment: Is it okay to modify the ArrayList items from within the Adapter? @pskink

Comment: it is not only ok, you have to do that

Comment: ViewHolder pattern is highly advised for ListView. That's why I use it @pskink

Comment: no it is not, in most cases hiew holder is useless (no standard google's ListView adapter uses that pattern)

Comment: Why can you store value in ViewHolder.?You create a ViewHolder, set it as tag to position 1. Next time, when you back to position 1, you use convertView,getTag() to get a ViewHolder stored in convertView.The tag of this convertView is from position 2 or 3, not the position 1.

Comment: @tinysunlight You sure your answer works? I still get empty values even after storing in the SparseArray

Comment: just use some adapter that uses list of your POJOs holding the data, `ArrayAdapter` for example

Comment: Is it possible to call the notifyDatasetChanged() from within the adapter after the user changes the values? @pskink

Comment: just try calling that method and see what happens, see `ArrayAdapter` sources for example on how it works: http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#189

Comment: @Earthling It's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store value in `ViewHolder`. You use `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` to get a `ViewHolder`. This `ViewHolder` is form tag of other view, its not the `ViewHolder` you store in this position.

```
private SparseArray<String> values = new SparseArray<>();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.saveName = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saveName);
            holder.nameField = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameField);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //Button That saves what the user entered in the nameField to the String variable
        holder.saveName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  values.put(position,nameField.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        //Just to check whether the value is saved when I recycle listview when scrolling
        Log.d("test", values.get(position,"null"));
        //It logs an empty string. The value from the editext was not saved! 
}

static class ViewHolder {
        EditText nameField;
        Button saveName;
        String hidden_value = "";
}
```

Comment: You sure this works? I still get empty values even after storing in the SparseArray

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, `ViewHolder` is supposed to hold the "Views" and not the "Data". You need to change your implementation here. Store the values in the array which you are passing to the adapter. This is the array which actually holds your "Data".

So, constructor of your custom adapter will be like,

```
public CategoryListViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<MyData> al) {
    mContext = c;
    mArrayList = al;
    ....
}
```

And `MyData` will have your ID field

```
class Mydata{
    String ID;
    ....
}
```

Please refer [this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) for complete tutorial on this topic. It has everything you need to know.